# append distinct dictionary values in list

Tags: python, mongodb, dictionary

I am storing list of dictionary in mongodb database.

Every hour I get list with list with new dictionary values, some dictionary might be same as previously inserted.

So I want to insert only distinct dictionaries in list and update that list in  mongo.

insert 1

```
res = [{"a": 1},{"b": 2},{"c": 4},{"d": 5},{"e": 6}]
```

insert 2

```
res = [{"f": 7},{"b": 2},{"c": 4},{"g": 8},{"h": 9}]
```

During second insert I will fetch `res` and will append new `res`. But while append, I want to take care of distinct dict in list.

Apart from check one by one all value in list, is there any python function to take care of this?

Or any way so that mongodb itself take care of this.

Answer (score 2):

As a python recipe for this task you can use a `set` as the container of your dictionary items (that are tuple) to preserve the unique elements then convert to dict again :

```
res1 = [{"a": 1},{"b": 2},{"c": 4},{"d": 5},{"e": 6}]
res2 = [{"f": 7},{"b": 2},{"c": 4},{"g": 8},{"h": 9}]

>>> [{i:j} for i,j in {next(i.iteritems()) for i in res1+res2}]
[{'a': 1}, {'b': 2}, {'e': 6}, {'f': 7}, {'h': 9}, {'c': 4}, {'g': 8}, {'d': 5}]
```

Answer (score 1):

[upsert](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/distinct/) should do what you're looking for:

```
for key in res.keys():
    db.collection.update(
       {username:key},
       {$set:{'value':res[key]}},
       {upsert: true}
)
```

Alternatively, do it in python using sets.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking for the $addToSet operator in MongoDB:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet